# Connecting forms with pushButton c++ QT

Tags: c++, forms, qt, qpushbutton

I am creating a program that requires a form to be opened, and the previous to be closed on a push button click.  My current problem is that when I click the button the new form is shown for a millisecond then disappears.

```
void mainMenu::on_mainLoginB_clicked()
{
     logIn objlogIn;
     objlogIn.show();
}

void mainMenu::on_mainExitB_clicked()
 {
     exit(1);
 }
```

here is my header file

```
private slots:
    void on_mainLoginB_clicked();

    void on_mainExitB_clicked();

private:
    Ui::mainMenu *ui;


};
```

Answer (score 3):

`objLogIn` is declared in the scope of the SLOT, and for this reason, deleted when the function return.

Remember that QT, like most user interfaces works with an event (message) loop, so functions like `show()` do not block: they immediately return and it is the event loop managing it further.

For solving this issue:

- Create the object in a higher scope and show it/hide it when required.
- Create the object dynamically in the heap.

Comment: assuming that op wants user to enter login/password and verify it, I'd say a better solution would be to inherit login form from QDialog, not QWidget, and in on_clicked() slot create dialog, call exec(), and process result that exec() returns.

Comment: That is a broad topic, but you probably want to tell this to the OP and not to this answer?

Comment: Your answer is correct and you pointed 2 ways to solve issue, i just pointed one more.